# Is it possible make reference by key?

Tags: commercetools

Is it possible to set `Reference<Channel>` value in custom field with type `Reference` by channel key?

Because for now I have to find channel that I need by its key, get Id from it and make a reference!

```
Reference<Channel> channelRef = Channel.referenceOfId("channel CT id");
```

Perhaps there is another way to make Reference through the key? Or there is only way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this questions about Referencing channel by key. 
In our documentation you will find that some resources do support reference resource identifier by key. Unfortunately channel is not one of them. The only way to set this currently is by using the id like you described.

https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-types#resourceidentifier

Our team will look into this topic and see if there is any way we can document more clearly which resources can be set using key.